# How to make a typeless/generalized parameter in Java?

Tags: java, types, parameter-passing

So say I have 2 methods: one adding two int's and the other adding two long's.  Where the parameters are passed into the function.

How can I make 1 method that generalizes the parameter and return value to perform this?

Comment: In Java you can have two methods with the different arguments and the same name. In the situation you described this is most likely preferable because it can be done with primitives types without going for objects and generics (unless this is a university homework not really related to Java but to general concepts).

Comment: Not homework, just a question I had.

Comment: Brandon: This sort of requirement rarely has any purpose in real-life situations. Mind if we ask why you're trying to do this?

Comment: It seems redundant to write two different methods in order to have the same functionality.

Answer (score 7):

I saw a trick like this in GWT:

```
public static <T> T add(long a, long b)
{
    return (T)(Object)(a + b); 
}
```

Use it like this:

```
long answer = add(1L, 2L);
int answer2 = add(1, 2);
```

While this does what you're asking for, the downside of this approach is that it opens you up to bad type casts. Even though you don't have to explicitly cast the value that is returned, you're still effectively telling the code to perform a cast to whatever the expected type is.  You could accidentally say something like:

```
String t = add(1, 2);
```

Which would cause a runtime exception. Nevertheless, if you have a method whose return value will always be cast immediately after being returned, this trick can save consumers the hassle of explicitly casting the value.

Comment: Hm... when I run this, I have to declare the variables as Integer and Long. Compilation fails when I use primitives. And I get a runtime exception for a failed Integer<->Long cast.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't actually try compiling and running this, but Eclipse wasn't complaining so I assumed it would at least compile.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, I don't think you can do this. First, [Java generics can't be parameterized over primitives](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeArguments.html#Are%20primitive%20types%20permitted%20as%20type%20arguments?), so you'd have to use `Integer` and `Long` instead of `int` and `long`. Second, while you could have a method with generic type parameter `T extends Number`, there's no way to add two arbitrary `Number` subclasses in a generic fashion. In other words, the following code will *not* work:

```
public static <T extends Number> T add(T a, T b) {
    return a + b; // Won't compile, as the addition is not legal Java code.
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? If I'm mistaken, and there is a way to do this, I'd really like to know how.

Comment: Was writing my comment about why I downvoted when you made that comment. Anyway... Your first sentence is quite misleading. It's easy to use the wrapper classes for primitives, and your latter point is probably a nonissue because Brandon's existing methods are for adding two ints and two longs, which implies that he wants the generic method to have that same functionality and not necessarily be able to add an int and a long.

Comment: Yes.  Only for adding two ints and two longs.

Comment: @JAB: Brandon specifically asked about ints and longs, not Integers and Longs. While the difference is often unimportant due to autoboxing, it still exists, and it's a good thing to be aware of. I do agree that he doesn't want to be able to add an `int` and `long`. I think he's asking how to write a single method that takes two parameters, either both ints or both longs, adds them, and returns a value of the same type as the two parameters. As far as I know, this is impossible in Java without manual type checks and casts, at which point his two method approach is probably better.

Comment: Yes. I'm looking for a single method.

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java

Answer (score 0):

```
long f(long x, long y){ ... }

int x=1, y=2;
f(x,y);
```

Comment: This doesn't do exactly what the OP wants, since `int z = f(x,y)` won't compile without casting the return value of `f` to `int`.